# Equivalent vectors for dot product

Tags: vectors

> Suppose there are $2$ vectors such that vector dot product of them i.e $\langle a,b,c \rangle \cdot \langle x,y,z \rangle  = C$ i.e $C$ is a scalar quantity. Is there a way to find out another vector such that when we do dot product with $\langle x,y,z \rangle$ it also gives $C$?

Example is $\langle 6,0,0 \rangle  \cdot \langle 2,3,7 \rangle  = 12$ and also $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle  \cdot \langle 2,3,7 \rangle  = 12$. So how do we find all such vectors such that when multipled by $\langle 2,3,7 \rangle $ it gives result $12$.

Is there any concept that I can use for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a name for this concept. If your space is three-dimensional, it's called a *plane*. One usually writes the collection of all such vectors $[x, y, z]$ as
$$
2x+3y+7z = 12
$$
but your dot product notation
$$
[x, y, z]\cdot [2, 3, 7] = 12
$$
also works.

It is called a "plane" because the collection of all such vectors (if you're used to thinking about vectors as arrows, then the collection of all possible *end points* of all those vectors, if they start at the origin) makes an entirely flat surface, which is what a plane is. This surface is orthogonal / normal to the vector $[2, 3, 7]$, and $[2, 3, 7]$ is therefore called a *normal vector* to that plane.

Comment: Well thanks.I still have 2 things to be answed.Does the planes still work if instead I have N -dimensions ? And what do i use to generate all such points in a plane

Comment: @poseidon_rishi In more dimensions you do the same thing, only with more terms (for instance, with $[2, 3, 7, 4]$, and dot product equal to $12$, you get $2x+3y+7z+4w = 12$, and in general $N$ dimensions it's called a _hyperplane_). And to generate all the points, you solve for one of the variables (say $z = \frac{12-2x-3y}{7}$), and just insert any values for $x$ and $y$ you want, and get the corresponding values for $z$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation
$$
C = [x, y, z] \cdot [a, b, c] = n \cdot u
$$
with fixed $[x, y, z]$ and varying $[a, b, c]$ is, for non-zero $[x,y,z]$, the equation of an affine plane (meaning it is possible that the plane does not contain the origin) with normal vector $n=[x,y,z]$ and distance
$\lvert C \rvert / \lVert n \rVert$ to the origin.